# How can I check if an input is outside the bounds of my dictionary list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a file called "periodic_table". Inside this file is multiple lines. Each line has an atomic number on the side and a corresponding element name on the right like this:

```
1 Hydrogen
2 Helium
3 Lithium
4 Beryllium
5 Boron
6 Carbon
7 Nitrogen
8 Oxygen
9 Fluorine
10 Neon
11 Sodium
12 Magnesium
13 Aluminium
14 Silicon
etc...
```

I made a program that asks for either the element name or number, and prints out the corresponding value in the dictionary. If the user inputs 1 it will print Hydrogen, similarly if the user inputs Silicon it will output 14. HOWEVER - I want the program to inform the user if he enters a non existent atomic number (such as 150) or a non existent element (such as Blanket or any other string). I tried using an `if` but it printed out an infinite loop:

```
element_list = {}
name = input("Enter element number or element name: ")
while name:
    with open("periodic_table.txt") as f:
        for line in f:
           (key, val) = line.split()
           element_list[int(key)] = val
           if name == key:
               print(val)
           elif name == val:
               print(key)
    name = input("Enter element number or element name: ")
```

Comment: Is it python 2.x or python 3.x?

Answer (score 4):

For minimal changes to your existing code, you could set a flag `found` if the element is found, and act on it accordingly. So:

```
    found = False
    for line in f:
        # ....
        if name == key:
            print(val)
            found = True
        elif ...
    if not found:
        print("Not an element or atomic number: {}".format(name))
```

Comment: I would, if I knew how to implement that on my code. I have never used the found feature. Sorry for sounding so newbie, but I have not used Python in a LONG time. How would my program look with your current method?

Comment: There is no "found" feature. I just introduced a variable which I called `found` (I could have used any other name) and showed you how you could change your code to use it. You should be able to add it to your existing code following the example I have given.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply quit your program as soon as a match is found. If no match is found, the user will be prompted for input again. Otherwise the program will terminate after printing the corresponding number/name.

```
# http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html
import sys

#variable below is not doing much!
#element_list = {}
name = input("Enter element number or element name: ")
#Changed loop to be infinite
while True:
    with open("periodic_table.txt") as f:
        for line in f:
           (key, val) = line.split()
           element_list[int(key)] = val
           if name == key:
               print(val)
               sys.exit()
           elif name == val:
               print(key)
               sys.exit()
    #If something is found, it will never reach this
    print("No match found... try again!")
    name = input("Enter element number or element name: ")
```

Comment: That only seems to ask for input once, then exit. I added "name = input("Enter element number or element name: ") under if name == key and elif name == val and removed sys.exit(). It now does every correct EXPECT it prints "No match found... try again!" sometimes (Ie, if I type 1 in prints hydrogen but if I try it again it might print No match found... try again!).

Answer (score 1):

To efficiently solve this problem (without reading the file repeatedly) you need to break it down into two steps, which your current code is mixing together. First, read the file and prepare the dictionary mapping between element names and numbers. Second, process user input and check against the dictionary.

```
# step 1, build the mapping
element_list = {}
with open("periodic_table.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        number, name = line.split()
        element_list[number] = name
        element_list[name] = number # map in both directions

# step 2, test user input (quits after an empty input)
user_entry = input("Enter element number or name: ")
while user_entry:
    try:
        print(element_list[user_entry])
    except KeyError:
        print("Unrecognized number or name.")
    user_entry = input("Enter element number or name: ")
```